# true == false evaluates to true somehow?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I've been working to scrape some webpage that is using the OWASP CRSFGuard project for protection. The library seems to be causing one of my requests to get a 401 so I started digging through their code and noticed the following;

```
function isValidDomain(current, target) {
    var result = false;

    /** check exact or subdomain match **/
    if(current == target || current == 'localhost') {
        result = true;
    } else if(true == false) {
        if(target.charAt(0) == '.') {
            result = current.endsWith(target);
        } else {
            result = current.endsWith('.' + target);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

From what I can tell, there must be instances where this code is executed; `result = current.endsWith('.' + target);`. Given `true == false` is inherently false, how would the code reach that statement? Is this some JS oddity (I know we're not using the strict === equality, but seriously...)?

Comment: That never happens.  if(true == false) console.log('WTF!');

Comment: This happens with this example exactly, or are you assuming that is being generated one `true` in `} else if(true == false) {`?

Comment: `if(true == false)` makes no sense.

Comment: Perhaps a developer wanted to "comment out" that bit of code, but that doesn't explain why he didn't simply use `if (false)` or a `/* comment block */`

Comment: Show an example of using that happens the problem. Like: `console.log(isValidDomain(x, y));`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento I'm assuming it's evaluating to true, I haven't executed that code directly, PhantomJS is loading the script it's in and by monitoring my HTTP traffic I concluded code went through that path. Seems likely I was wrong about that.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal But is to show an example of the problem or not? :)

Comment: @Vohuman agreed, but I'm not very familiar with JS, am aware it's comparisons are eccentric, and saw the code in a commonly used/well support library so I thought I'd ask. I'm not sure why my requests to different subdomains are able to get a CSRF token still but I trust that I'm mistaken in thinking the code executed through that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:** It will never reach that code block.

```js
function isValidDomain(current, target) {
  var result = false;

  /** check exact or subdomain match **/
  if (current == target || current == 'localhost') {
    result = true;
  } else if (true == false) {
    if (target.charAt(0) == '.') {
      result = current.endsWith(target);
    } else {
      result = current.endsWith('.' + target);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

var trueFalse = document.getElementById('trueFalse');
trueFalse.innerHTML = isValidDomain('true', 'false') ? 'WTF!' : 'All is good in the JS World';

trueFalse.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  trueFalse.innerHTML = (true == false) ? 'WTF!' : 'All is good in the JS World Still';
});
```

```html
<div id="trueFalse"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say that Blazemonger is most likely correct.

That `else if` probably had some other condition at some point, and for whatever reason, they decided they didn't want that block of code to execute anymore, so they changed the condition to something that is always false.

It's also not entirely uncommon to see programmers use `1 === 0` as an indication for `false`. Why they would want to do this is anybody's guess.